# Docusign connect service not posting data to specified url

Tags: docusignapi

Docusign connect service is not posting data to the url specified in the connect service option. Actually if i resend the data from log it works but it do not works on its own.
Please help me
Thanks

Comment: What events and users do you have Connect configured for?  Is it only for envelope completed you are listening for, do you have all events checked, etc?  Same with users, are you testing for just one user that you have checked in the config settings, or is this for all users?  And are you testing with an http or https address?

Comment: Also, can you please go to Preferences -> Connect -> Logs and add a sample (failure) log to to your question? That will give us some good info on what you're sending, to where, status, etc.  If needed you can redact any sensitive info, although since this is on the demo server I don't suspect there should be...

Answer (score 3):

Usually when DocuSign Connect is not publishing to a URL it is caused by one of a few things:

1. Your server is not listening on the correct port(s).
2. You are not testing for the correct events.
3. You do not have the user (sender) configured for Connect.
4. Your server is not publicly accessible.
5. Your firewall or network security is not letting the requests going through.
6. Your server has crashed.
7. A potential bug with DocuSign Connect.

Possible resolutions:

1. If testing in DocuSign demo environment (demo.docusign.net) ports 80 (http) and 443 (https) are allowed.  If testing in production environment (www.docusign.net) only 443 - https is allowed.
2. Make sure you are testing for the correct event triggers - this can be confirmed on your Connect settings page.  Login to the Console and go to Preferences -> Connect -> (select one of your Connect configurations).  On the following page you'll see how to select events that you want Connect to push on, as well as for which users.
3. Followup answer to 2 - you need to also make sure you have the correct account members enabled for Connect on the Console -> Preferences -> Connect page.
4. You can **not** use a localhost address for the Connect URL - it must be a publicly accessible URL.
5. Your network administrator might have a firewall (physical or virtual) or other security software setup that is stopping the requests from going through.  Check your security settings and test that the proper ports are enabled, etc.
6. Ensure that your server is still up and running and that it hasn't crashed.
7. Although DocuSign Connect has been around for some time it still occasionally exhibits a bug or two.  If not one of the other potential reasons then provide the failure log in your post and someone from DocuSign will follow up.

If you are running into issues with DocuSign Connect hopefully one of the above remedies resolve your issue.

Comment: Do you mean Port 443 for HTTPS?