# Docusign Connect - Can't connect to my server error

Tags: docusignapi

I'm using my dev account and trying to test the *DocuSign Connect service* which does not seem to be working for me.  When I look a the DocuSign connect log, I see this error message

> Error: Exception in EnvelopeIntegration.RunIntegration: 1d84faf8-de43-44fc-a709-efa044ac740a........Error - Unable to connect to the remote server; A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond...

I'm logging connections to the port on my firewall that I expect the service to connect to (it's specified in the URL).  I see other connections to that port in my firewall log, but never an attempt by the *Docusign Connect Service*.

Any ideas where the issue might be?

Answer (score 3):

DocuSign Connect will only publish to the "standard/default" ports:

- In the DocuSign demo environment (demo.docusign.net) DocuSign Connect will publish to either port 80 (**http**) or port 443 (**https**). If the URL starts with "**http**", Connect will attempt to publish to **port 80**. If the URL starts with "**https**", Connect will attempt to publish to **port 443**.
- In the DocuSign production environment (www.docusign.net), DocuSign Connect will only publish to **port 443** (**https**).  Publishing to **port 80** (**http**) is ***not supported*** in the production environment -- the listener endpoint must be **https**.

Therefore, I'd suggest that you remove the port number from the URL that you've specified for the DocuSign Connect configuration, and ensure that your listener endpoint is located at either port 80 (for demo) or port 443 (for demo or prod).  If that doesn't resolve your issues, then you might want to review the Answer for this other forum post:  [Docusign connect service not posting data to specified url](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18097132/docusign-connect-service-not-posting-data-to-specified-url).

Comment: Hello, instead of using Connect service am using eventNotification in the request when uploading my document to Docusign. In that am supplying my URL. It has a port which I got opened to public after a big fight from my networking team. This is how my URL looks: http://x.x.x.x:8086/api/DocuSign/DocuSignDocumentStatus. From your answer above I guess this one also won't work. Am I right?

Comment: That's correct -- it won't work if the URL contains a port number.  The "eventNotification" mechanism that you're using relies on the same underlying mechanism as DocuSign Connect, so the answer above still applies.