# DocuSign Connect notifications in DocuSign demo account

Tags: docusignapi

We are having issues with Connect notifications from our DocuSign demo account.We are not able to receive any updates from our Connect configuration. Though, when I republished the XML from Connect logs, I did receive a Connect update to a specified URL.
When I created new envelopes using API as well as from DocuSign account itself, I never got any notifications to the same URL.I do not even see a Connect log.

We do not have any issues with Connect notifications for our DocuSign live account.
We have never experienced this issue before with Connect updates from our DocuSign demo account.

Please advise.

Comment: Maaaaybe http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20590234/docusign-connect-cant-connect-to-my-server-error?rq=1

Comment: Can you post a picture of your Demo Connect configuration? (you can blank out the endpoint URL and names if you'd like)

Comment: Are there any errors showing up in the error logs for the first time the updates are supposed to go out?

Comment: There were no error logs in the configuration.We are able to get the Connect updates today fine. May be it was happening only yesterday.

Comment: Hmm yeah might have been a temporary issue.  If you're working in the demo environment that's a little more expected.  Production (www) environment is much more stable...

Answer (score 0):

Just a hunch - do you use http or https? connect can only work over port 443 with a valid SSL certificate. If you're on localhost - you may need to get a temp certificate or something like that but also using azure websites is good way to avoid this issue since they're pretty much just as good as working on your localhost