# 'eventNotification' url is not being called

Tags: asp.net-mvc, docusignapi

I am integrating DocuSign with our application. In testing phase we got a server with public IP and port (8086). On this port I have published my asp.net mvc web api and my url becomes:
http://XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX:8086/api/DocuSign/DocuSignDocumentStatus.

This url is going to be called from DocuSign whenever my document status changes.

Our network team has allowed access to following IPs for inbound access to this public IP/URL:
www.docusign.net 209.67.98.12

mailsea.docusign.net 209.67.98.59

NA2

na2.docusign.net 206.25.247.140

mailch.docusign.net 206.25.247.155

EU1

eu1.docusign.net 206.25.247.144

mailch.docusign.net 206.25.247.155

DAL/DR

demo.docusign.net 209.46.117.172

preview.docusign.net 209.46.117.174

mailda.docusign.net 209.46.117.17

I got this from the connect service reference pdf.

Whenever I am uploading the document from signing via docuSign web api and I am also sending this url with the request. I have checked - rechecked many times that my json request being created is correct (*pasting it below*):

```
 {
  "status": "sent",
  "emailBlurb": "",
  "emailSubject": "DocuSign API - Signature Request on Document Call",
  "documents": [
    {
      "name": "someDocument.xls",
      "documentId": "1"
    }
  ],
  "recipients": {
    "signers": [
      {
        "recipientId": "1",
        "email": "john.doe@someCompany.com",
        "name": "John Doe",
        "tabs": {
          "signHereTabs": [
            {
              "xPosition": "100",
              "yPosition": "100",
              "documentId": "1",
              "pageNumber": "1"
            }
          ]
        },
        "routingOrder": "1"
      }
    ],
    "carbonCopies": [
      {
        "recipientId": "2",
        "email": "some1.recipient@someCompany.com",
        "name": "Some1 Recipient"
      },
      {
        "recipientId": "3",
        "email": "some2.recipient@someCompany.com",
        "name": "Some2 Recipient"
      },
      {
        "recipientId": "4",
        "email": "some3.recipient@someCompany.com",
        "name": "Some3 Recipient"
      }
    ]
  },
  "eventNotification": {
    "url": "http://XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX:8086/api/DocuSign/DocuSignDocumentStatus",
    "loggingEnabled": true,
    "requireAcknowledgement": true,
    "includeDocuments": false,
    "envelopeEvents": [
      {
        "envelopeEventStatusCode": "Completed"
      },
      {
        "envelopeEventStatusCode": "Declined"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

I am able successfully upload the document, emails are being sent successfully to all signers. Document being signed BUT DocuSign for some reason is not able to call my url with the status of the document. Please help. Let me know if you guys need any more information.

Answer (score 2):

As specified by the Answer & subsequent Comment in [this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20590234/docusign-connect-cant-connect-to-my-server-error/20591075):

Regardless of whether you're using DocuSign Connect (configured at the account level) or using **eventNotification** (specified at the Envelope level), DocuSign will only publish messages to the "standard/default" ports:

In the DocuSign **demo** environment (demo.docusign.net) DocuSign Connect will publish to either **port 80 (http)** or **port 443 (https)**. If the URL starts with "http", Connect will attempt to publish to port 80. If the URL starts with "https", Connect will attempt to publish to port 443.

In the DocuSign **production** environment (www.docusign.net), DocuSign Connect will only publish to **port 443 (https)**. Publishing to port 80 (http) is not supported in the production environment -- the listener endpoint must be https.

Therefore, I'd suggest that you remove the port number from the URL that you've specified for "eventNotification", and ensure that your listener endpoint is located at either port 80 (for demo) or port 443 (for demo or prod).

Comment: I tested this call on my 443 listener and it works perfectly. Kim is right about the port requirements :)

Comment: So the only problem is here to open port 40 for public access since its http. And give the url at envelope level without port. Eg: x.x.x.x/docusign... Right?. Hope you have cross verified my json request.

Comment: Yes, but it's Port 80 for http (not port 40).

Comment: oh sry .... yes, port 80 it is. Thanks a ton. Let me test it on port  40 and I will let you all the result.