# Docusign API runs into timeout when published "A connection attempt failed"

Tags: c#, docusignapi

I programmed a small web based solution based on https://github.com/docusign/code-examples-csharp

Everything works fine while i am in Visual Studio IDE.

If the Session is new and the user is not logged in, he is redirected to the DocuSign login page. After entering his credentials he is send back to the https://localhost:16123/ds/callback page. and th programm works fine

Then i published the solution to a webserver (not accessable from outside) and get the error "A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond." when it tries to redirect to my page.

I read at [Docusign connect service not posting data to specified url](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18097132/docusign-connect-service-not-posting-data-to-specified-url) that the domain must be accessable from internet, but the post was 7 years ago. Is this still the soliution, cause i have  no chance to publish it public.

### EDITED:

Reproduction:

1. Download Excamples from https://github.com/docusign/code-examples-csharp
2. Copy appsettings.example.json to appsettings.json and edit it
3. Insert ClientID, ClientSecret, in part "DocuSign", change Appurl to https://{computername}.org.{company}.local, set quickstart to false
4. Inserted my internal addres https://{computername}.org.{company}.local/ds/callback to redirecion urls

Actions: Start browser , go to https://computername.org.company.local, select authenticate with Docusign, entered User and Passwort. After about 30 seconds i was directed tot the page
https://{computername}.org.{company}.local/Home/Error?message=A%20connection%20attempt%20failed%20because%20the%20connected%20party%20did%20not%20properly%20respond%20after%20a%20period%20of%20time,%20or%20established%20connection%20failed%20because%20connected%20host%20has%20failed%20to%20respond.

Comment: Hi Markus Roessler, welcome to Stackoverflow! When asking questions, it's helpful to have a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) to best assist with helping your question.

Comment: Hi  Richard Kenneth Niescior, I added informations to reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what your webserver is exactly, but you would have to enable the firewall/proxy/antivirus etc. to allow your app to make API calls FROM the server directly. A simple locked down webserver does not allow these calls typically and you would have to work with your networking folks to enable this. We have seen situation where GET calls were allowed but not POST (or vice versa) and that won't do either.

This is not even about the webhooks/Connect where DocuSign is calling INTO your server. This is about just your server making calls outside and these are blocked for you.

I wish you explore using a public cloud such as AWS/Azure etc. as it makes all of this much easier and is just as secure.

Comment: Hi Inbar Gazit, i gave the informations to our networ folks, hope they can help me.